# Delete files that do not contain ".zip" in their filename

Tags: find

I am trying to find and delete files that don't have ".zip" in it and is bigger than 1 Gig.
I found the following command. Can someone explain to me what the following command is doing?

```
/etc/home -type f  -name "*.log*" ! -name "*.zip"  -size +1G  -delete;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this command instead :

```
find /etc/home -type f -size +1G ! -name "*.zip" | xargs rm
```

if you insist on using the -delete construct, please note that this option turns on the `-depth` switch in `find` and will reach in any subdirectory under /etc/home and find matching files for this criteria and delete them. If you are okay with that, just replace `|xargs rm` with `-delete`. See the man page of `find` command, for further details.